# Batch the "Extract Here" command

Tags: command-line, batch, 7-zip, extract

I would like to batch the "Extract Here..." command on a complete folder. Every type of archive should be unzipped into the current folder with the name of the archive file. I have found some BATCH scripts for just *.zip, but I don't care what kind of archive it is, as long as my archiver can open it.

Does anyone know what kind of archiver has such a batching funcionality? I can't seem to find it in 7-zip or winrar.

In pseudo:

```
Given folder x
foreach archiveFile in x or descendant of x
unzip archiveFile.extension >> "folder of archiveFile/archiveFile"
```

*Update*
I have tried the following for only zip files:

```
dir /s /b *.zip > allzips.txt
for /F %%x in (allzips.txt) do unzip %%x
```

Where `unzip` is still an unknown function.

Comment: Can you paste your code for the .zip here and I will adapt it.

Comment: @William There you go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*EDIT* Given: Using batch script.

You may wish to use a third party zip tool (highly recommend 7-ZIP command line version called 7z.exe) to accomplish this.

with 7z, the syntax is as follows:

```
7z <command> [<switch>...] <base_archive_name> [<arguments>...]
```

To extract the command would be:

```
7z e file.zip -y
```

the -y switch assume "Yes" answer to any questions that may come up during extraction such as overwrite requests.

So your command will read

```
CD "C:\Location\Of\ZipFiles"
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%F IN (`DIR /b *.zip`) DO (7z e "%%F" -y)
```

If you want to output them into a different location, you can use the -o switch and specify the directory:

```
7z e "%%F" -y -oC:\Some\Other\Folder\
```

EDIT:

To perform the extract with full paths and specifying all ZIP archives only, use this:

```
7z x -tzip "C:\Location\of\zips\*"
```

Or even nutzier... all ZIP files on C: drive:

```
7z x -r -tzip "C:\*"
```

EDIT2:

Making it compatible with your output file, this:

```
dir /s /b *.zip > allzips.txt
for /F %%x in (allzips.txt) do (7z x -tzip "%%x")
```

Comment: I would like to maintain the folder and output them at the location itself. Shouldn't I use the `x` instead of `e`? And: This is still for zip files only. Isn't there a way to just say: all archive-kind-of-files?

Comment: So you want to pull ALL ZIP FILES from anywhere on the drive and tell them to extract where they sit into a folder named the same as the zip file? And no in 7z the extract option is 'e'

Comment: You can use 'x' instead of 'e' to preserve the full path yes. My mistake.